# Serilog's AddSerilog is not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm trying to call **loggerFactory.AddSerilog();** as per [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-docker/blob/master/web-sample/src/Program.cs) documentation, but the **AddSerilog** method is not recognized:

"Error  CS1061  'ILoggerFactory' does not contain a definition for 'AddSerilog' and no extension method 'AddSerilog' accepting a first...".

I'm using ASP.NET CORE with the full .NET framework.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your project.json file

Comment: `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Serilog": "2.1.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer": "4.0.0"`

Comment: That's just part of the file. I can't include all of it because of too many characters.

Comment: OK found it, my bad.... forgot to install package **Serilog.Extensions.Logging**... thanks Joe, your comment helped me in the right direction.

Comment: just for future reference, when I asked you to post project.json, I meant edit your question and add it there, it would have fit there but not in comments

Comment: Great, thanks a lot Joe, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You may forget this following line in project.json

`"Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",`

See also https://carlos.mendible.com/2016/09/19/step-step-serilog-asp-net-core/

Comment: THANKYOU.  This has been driving me insane.  NO WHERE is this mentioned.  all the tutorials, and git hub, all mention the serilog main dll, and serilog.extensions.logging.file, BUT NO ONE, tells you anywhere that you need this one too.  To add insult to injury, there's a weak resference to it in the main lib, so dotnetcore resolves the lib base, but not the method, so there's no indication that you need another lib, in intellisense.  I'd up vote a million times if I could.

Comment: Carlos has updated his post as of Jan 2019 for .NET Core 2.2: https://carlos.mendible.com/2019/01/14/updated-step-step-serilog-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 41):

Different circumstance, but same problem. In my case, I was using .Net Core 2.1 and had a NuGet reference to *Serilog*, but was missing a reference to *Serilog.AspNetCore*. The issue first manifested as .UserSerilog() not being found for the IWebHostBuilder of my CreateWebHostBuilder static method under Program.cs.

Adding the *Serilog.AspNetCore* NuGet package to my project solved the problem.

Comment: This was needed for .Net Core 3.1 as well.

Answer (score 22):

The posted answer is correct but I will add that you may want to use the NuGet package manager that way you can get the latest version.

> Right click on solution
>
> -> Choose "Manage NuGet packages for solution"
>
> -> type "serilog.extensions.logging" into search box
>
> -> Click on Serilog.Extensions.Logging and press install

You will get a dropdownlist of the different versions you should choose the latest.

Or quicker from Package Manager console verify that Default Project drop-down has your project selected and run

```
install-package Serilog.Extensions.Logging
```

Comment: Good info. Thanks James.

Answer (score 5):

On .NET Core 3.1, within a console app, I simply had to install the **serilog.extentions.hosting** NuGet package.

[image]

This will add the below line to the **ItemGroup** within *YourProjectName*.csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.7" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have package `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` added to your project already, it could be just a matter of adding `using Serilog;` to the top of your code file.